# ionic 2 Sqlite Storage

Tags: sqlite, types, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2. i am trying to transfer a list of data i stored in a variable called viewData into Sqlite storage.

```
constructor(private app: App, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private modalCtrl: ModalController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public storage: Storage) {



this.viewData = this.navParams.get('_body.data');
console.log(this.viewData);

storage.ready().then(() => {

   // set a key/value
    this.storage.set('userInfo', this.viewData);
    console.log('userInfo');
}); }
```

please what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('userInfo');
```

First you have to take userInfo from the storage and then print it:

```
storage.set('userInfo', this.viewData);
    storage.get('userInfo').then( (value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
```